# one of 2 websites pointing to same root folder not working well

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

One of my client has IIS with 2 web sites running, pointing to same app pool and root folder. Lets say those 2 websites as a.com and b.com, pointing to same root folders. Now that b.com works well, but a.com throws 500 internal server error. Browsing within the server gives me the error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module
>      IIS Web Core
>
> Notification
>      Unknown
>
> Handler
>      Not yet determined
>
> Error Code
>      0x80070005
>
> Config Error
>      Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
>
> Config File
>      \?\C:\Inetpub\vhosts\Server\2\web.config
>
> Physical Path
>
> Logon Method
>      Not yet determined
>
> Logon User
>      Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:
>      -1: 
>       0:

The actual web.config file (under root folder) is somewhere else, and the above config location shown in the error is something else. Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue.? I am not aware of any permissions to this web.config and it was working fine earlier. No such permission changes done recently.

Answer (score 1):

Typically that error is presented when the app pool user has no permissions on the app folder. Since you say both web sites are using the same app pool is kind of weird that one is working and the other isn't. I'd suggest that you inspect a little bit more in the IIS logs and see if you find more useful information.

Comment: IIS log file doesn't have any error reported. All that has is like: GET <URL and contents> 403 502 0 1

Comment: have you checked the physical path for site a.com? I know you mention that both sites are pointing the same folder but I wanted to confirm (It's under website>Advanced settings). One more question: did you browse the site locally? IIS details errors better when browsing from the localhost.

Comment: Yes, I did. Physical path is correct. The above error is from localhost browsing. Nothing more than that is displayed. And as I mentioned, the permission issue is not for this physical path web.config, the error says some other path's web.config permission issue. But still I checked there, this app pool user has all permissions (except special permissions) enabled.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest to create a second app pool and change the site a.com to use that app pool and create a second folder and see if the error persists, try to play with what the error might be. Also check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0 even though there are many responses and the error is too generic. Sorry I wasn't helpful enough.

Comment: No worries, I just renamed that folder and that issue is resolved. Some caching issue I guess. Thanks for your help.